# Android Emulator Screen Size Issue

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

My Android studio emulator screen is off the original positioning and I have tried resizing, reloading the emulator, and Android studio to no avail.

What is wrong with the emulator Display?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013216/android-emulator-screen-size-not-the-same-as-device-frame?newreg=6126001ef1804b338f533b40bcdb0711 this is the link to place where I was able to solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013216/android-emulator-screen-size-not-the-same-as-device-frame?newreg=6126001ef1804b338f533b40bcdb0711 this is the link to place where I was able to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but I [had this same problem (together with the side panel menu being overly large)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqY21.png) after updating from Android Studio 2.3.0 to 2.3.1.  After restarting my computer it went away...

Answer (score 3):

I have Alieanware 17 ( Dell Gaming Series ) when i updated my android studio version after week emulator screen shows small and not same size with skin fame size. i found in internet but no solutions after i searched many links   [Android Emulator Screen Size not the same as device frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013216/android-emulator-screen-size-not-the-same-as-device-frame) see this links help me but in that when i choose software option in graphic setting in emulator device configuration. my emulator going slow. it also say that use this option when computer graphic issue.

here images shows before setting apply and after setting apply

[image: software graphic setting]

[image: software graphic setting]

[image: software graphic setting]

[image: after choose software mode]

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem as Solanki after updating from 3.1.2 to 3.1.3 (and Gradle update). Configuring the AVD graphics from/to "Automatic" had no effect.

Restarting and (installing Windows 10 updates - coincidence?) solved the problem and all running normally on start up.

Answer (score 0):

you can just go to settings -> system -> scale and layout then change the size of text apps and other items to 125% restart android studio and run again the emulator.
good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Update android studio if it's not up to date then go to settings and then in emulator tab tick on "Launch in a tool window". It will work
[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REEgd.png)