# Android Studio emulator frame size is much bigger then the screen size

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, scaling

I tried to use Android Studio emulator on my Dell XPS 15 with 4K display (set to 200% scaling). There is a problem, however. The size of the emulator screen is fine, but the frame around it is enormous. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

I used Android Studio and it's emulators on this machine before, but it was more then a month ago and since then I reinstalled Windows once.

I tried to change emulated graphics setting like first answer in this question suggests: [Android Emulator Screen Size not the same as device frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013216/android-emulator-screen-size-not-the-same-as-device-frame)

But no luck, that dropdown is just grayed out for me, I can't do anything with it. Also, if I disable the frame in emulator settings, window for it is still very large compared to the "screen". What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to this problem. You should go to where your 'emulator.exe' is located (for me it's C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator) right-click 'emulator.exe', go to properties, and do the following:

1. Go to the 'Compatability' tab
2. Click on "Change high DPI settings"
3. Check 'Override high DPI scaling behavior" and chose 'System (Enhanced)' from the list.
   [image: Properties of 'emulator.exe' example]

Click Apply and then OK. Restart IDE and all should work well! :)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with my Windows 10 computer. Here is a solution that works for me:

1. Start Android Studio
2. Switch your screen resolution to 1920 x 1080 at 100% scale by going to windows display settings
   [image]
3. Once your screen resolution is at 1920 x 1080, start the android emulator
4. While the emulator is running, switch your resolution back to 3840 x 2160 at 200% scale and the emulator should look right

You will have to do this every time you start the emulator. 
Once you have it running properly in 4k DO NOT close the emulator because you will have to repeat the above steps.

Comment: Won't work for me. It's a windows laptop, I can't use a native 4K resolution, cause everything will be too small

Comment: What is your resolution set to when you have the android emulator running the way it currently is?

Comment: It's 4K with 200% scaling

Comment: Can you change your resolution on your laptop to 1920 x 1080?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, I will try it. The strange thing is, it worked fine a couple of months before

Comment: The Intel HAXM graphics plugin for the android emulator has had a few updates in the past months so that's what I think could be messing things up. Maybe you can try to revert back to an older version of HAXM and see if that fixes things also.