# Android emulator screen size bugged

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript

I have a Google Pixel emulator created via terminal, it works, the only thing is that the screen is all funky like this:

[image]

I found all the avd files and changed the screen size to what it should be, also the density but it resets back. Is there a way i can change the screen size using my terminal? I don't want to have to install Android Studio because i'm pretty sure it was making my emulator crash before. I want to use NativeScript, that's why i'm doing everything on my terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a combination of these commands:

- $ adb shell wm size 1080x1920
- $ adb shell wm density 480
- $ adb shell wm size reset
- $ adb shell wm density reset

However, I highly recommend that you setup your Android Virtual Device via the AVD Manager in Android Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html).  We have added a number of setup parameters & settings to make the AVD run fast on the Android Emulator. Once you have the AVD setup, running via command line should work with no problems. If you are having specific problems with AVDs and Emulator Crashes with Android Studio, please file a bug on: https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs

Comment: Hi, there's another bug with the screen size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539759/android-emulator-screen-size-issue, maybe you know how to fix it?