# How to solve this resizing of android emulator error? I am working on vscode but emulator is showing like below

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM4pq.png)

My emulator is showing like above, it is opening in this wide screen only. I have made a new virtual device on avd manager and changed most of the settings but I don't know how to resolve this issue.
Please let me know, thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539759/android-emulator-screen-size-issue)?

Comment: I have tried the various steps but it is still not working.

Comment: I tried to follow different steps mentioned in the post but none of them seems to work for me.

Comment: This _Restarting and (installing Windows 10 updates - coincidence?) solved the problem and all running normally on start up._  didn't work?

Comment: yep, I did this too and still I have the emulator like the one I shared